# How to pass ID to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In HTML, I have:

```
<td>
    <span id="change_naco"></span>
    <span id="naco">Food</span>
</td>            
<td>
    <span id="change_naco"></span>
    <span id="naco">apples</span>
</td>
```

The rows come from the MySQL query. I need to load them in the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    EditInPlace.defaults['save_url'] = 'php/save.php?id=150';
    $('naco').editInPlace({
        form_type: 'select',
        select_options: {
            '1':    'food',
            '2':    'apples',
            '3':    'oranges',
            '4':    'beer'
        },
        external_control: 'change_naco'
    });
</script>
```

I know that I must call my ID's differently, so I can do that by adding a number via PHP, for example, `change_naco1, change_naco2, change_naco3`, and `naco1, naco2, naco3`, but do I pass those ID names to the function?

It's for edit in place (dropdown menu). It's working fine for one ID, but when I load more lines from the query, it works only for the first one.

Comment: First post doesn't mean capitalisation optional!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to add the `editInPlace` call to a collection of DOM nodes. If that's the case then a class is much more appropriate than an ID since many DOM elements can share the same class. For example,

HTML:

```
    <td>
        <span id="change_naco1"></span>
        <span class="naco">Food</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="change_naco2"></span>
        <span class="naco">apples</span>
    </td>
```

JavaScript:

Notice the use of `.naco` instead of `naco`.  This form is a class selector.

```
$('.naco').editInPlace({
    form_type: 'select',
    select_options: {
        '1':    'food',
        '2':    'apples',
        '3':    'oranges',
        '4':    'beer'
    },
    external_control: 'change_naco'
});
```

Comment: You are still duplicating IDs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oops, fixed that

Comment: @JaredPar - What about external_control?

Comment: ok, but i neet to pass both ID names naco, and change_naco. I thought that the solution will be simpler. Simply send the name ID to the function. I can duplicate this code in php, but it won't be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an id requires a `#`. For example:

```
$('#naco')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that editinPlace to work for all items with an id starting with "naco", you can use this:

```
$('[id^="naco"]').editInPlace({
    form_type: 'select',
    select_options: {
        '1':    'food',
        '2':    'apples',
        '3':    'oranges',
        '4':    'beer'
    },
    external_control: 'change_naco'
});
```

Or, instead, give all of the same class of "naco" and use the selector ".naco"

Comment: That `]` looks a bit lonely. Take more care!

Comment: i also need to change the external_control: 'change_naco' to the correct ID name. how to do that?